# Getting the Bluetooth on an AC 7260 to work

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, bluetooth

Im using a HP Elitebook 8470p and recently bought a new WiFi card, the Intel AC 7260. The card also has Bluetooth included, which I figured to be nice, it could succede the laptop's original Bluetooth card BCM20702 (which is a separate card, mind you) as I was not particularly happy with it.

Upon installation of the AC 7260 I also disconnected the BCM20702, in order to avoid having two Bluetooth devices. The WiFi worked out of the box, on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 (both 64bit). The Bluetooth, however, did not even exist as a device, regardless have often, in what order or what version of drivers I installed.

My question: Is it even possible to get it to work? Since the motherboard is "wired" to "expect"  the  Bluetooth device to  be on a totally diffrent connector.

Comment: What was the original WiFi card that you replaced? Was it also a 2x2 dual-band card? I believe this laptop ships with either a Broadcom 2x2 dual-band or an Atheros 1x1 single band. If you had the Atheros, you may not have the right antennas for a 2x2 dual-band card.

Comment: It was an Intel Advanced N 3xxx, sorry I forgot which exactly. But as said, WiFi works perfectly, its the Bluetooth part that  worries me

Comment: Try the are new Intel drivers from October 2015 - [download here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/75439/Intel-Dual-Band-Wireless-AC-7260). Reboot after installation.

Comment: @harrymc I tried that before, so I suspected a hardware incompatibility

Comment: Yes, many reports on the Web about problems with that card. Most of them were solved by replacing it.

Comment: Keep noted this card is not official supported by your device model, [see: HP EliteBook 8470p Notebook PC - Spare Parts](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03673129)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some Wi-Fi/Bluetooth combo modules put the Bluetooth radio on USB or UART serial instead of PCIe (as I understand it, there are extra pins on an internal PCIe x1 connector that can be used for non-PCIe purposes such as USB). The AC 7260 spec docs seem to mention that it uses both PCIe and USB, so the Bluetooth functionality may be what it needs USB for. It's possible that your laptop's internal PCIe slot (where the previous Wi-Fi card was installed) does not have the "USB pins" of the PCIe slot connector actually hooked up to a USB host chip, so it's possible that your slot doesn't provide the USB connectivity that your AC 7260's Bluetooth functionality requires.

Comment: Would this be visible in terms of pins? Would pins be missing or would they just be unsed?

Comment: Dang. Do you have an advice how to best systematically detect such hidden hardware incompatibilities in the future? Apart from looking for complaints in random forums?

Comment: @Evgeni My take is that laptop wireless modules and antenna rigs have never really been standardized enough to be considered user-upgradeable. So don't bother. If your internal card doesn't meet your needs anymore, it's time to upgrade to a new laptop, or learn to live with a USB dongle.

Comment: Absolutely spot on answer. I would add though, the NGFF (M.2) standard's design does specifically address this issue by physically keying slots according to whether they support USB or not. So hopefully this issue will fade away with future laptops.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem just one week before as I tried to replace the 2.4 GHz only 7260n WiFi card on my Thinkpad x240, which originally support Bluetooth. I bought a 7260ac card from taobao.com and the lable on it is a little different than the normal 7260ac card. After I installed the card on the board and restarted, the 5 GHz WiFi worked like a charm. But the Bluetooth disappeared and can't be found in the device manager. I installed the latest Bluetooth device driver of Intel, tried the little Bluetooth on/off trick from the Lenovo engineer, and even reinstalled the windows 10 system. None of them worked.

I told the seller about the situation and they felt very wired too. Afterward they sent a new card to me which the label is same as the normal Lenovo 7260ac card. After I replaced the new card, the Bluetooth came back immediately. I wasted three days time to dealt with the Bluetooth function, which turned out it was just a wrong card.

So the conclusion is very simple, not every card is born equal. Just ask your seller replace a new card until it worked. If it still doens't work, replace a seller.

Answer (score 1):

These are used commonly on a lot of Dell and HP equipment and often give grief, I found that making sure the most upto date driver is the first step and can save a lot of time

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/75439/Intel-Dual-Band-Wireless-AC-7260

Make sure you get the correct one for the OS installed also this driver pack installs the wifi and the BT separately if I remember right and sometimes asks for authorisation to do BT install, so be sure that you give admin rights and agree to the install

all in all this is a good card and works well, but it does have known hardware mismatches issues

Answer (score 1):

Mine is a HP DV6 7000 series and after I upgraded my wireless/bt card to AC 7260, my bluetooth also disappeared. But I somehow managed to make it work. I don't know exactly what fixed it but here's what I did:

- I removed old drivers (Broadcom)
- I re-installed the driver for AC 7260 from Intel's website (I previously downloaded the driver from HP's)
- I installed the Bluetooth driver from Intel's website as well (wireless card and bt drivers are separate)
- Turn wifi off and on again (F12)

Then my Bluetooth's back. I paired it with my bt headset with no problem.

**UPDATES:** Later I found my bluetooth would disappear again everytime I reboot my computer, and it would reappear if I toggle wifi on and off. Then several weeks later I happened to **update BIOS** to a newer version and after reboot the bluetooth stayed working. So I guess you could try updating your BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with my Intel AC 3160, upgrading from a broadcom card on a samsung laptop. the wifi works just fine but the bluetooth is not detected at all. 
After some googling I found a video on youtube that suggested putting a piece of tape on one pin (the last pin on the right side), it seemed weird but it worked. Hope it helps check the [video](https://youtu.be/F_OWzdeNmD8)

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried an N 7260 on a 7 year old toshiba laptop, BT did not even register, wifi dual band was ok, had BT drivers for it but system could not find any bluetooth device. So tried Atheros QCA9377 card instead, which is better I think, that worked straight away no problems with windows 10, did not even have to install drivers for it wifi dual band and bluetooth worked. So I guess it's just a hardware compatibility issue as I suspected. Suggest you try another card. Find out what pins do what and can your machine accomodate this.